# Total minutes from datetime value

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, minute

How to get total time in minutes from datetime?

```
18/11/2013 07:31:04
```

The result should be: 451 min (it's 07*60 + 31).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the hour and minute components of your date time with `HOUR()` and `MINUTE()` functions and combine them with this formula

```
=HOUR(A1)*60+MINUTE(A1)
```

Comment: Caveat: don't format with TEXT() because, as a side effect, it prevents to use the result as a number in some other formula. Instead, change the Cell Format.